# What are the advantages of using virtual machine with remote desktop at home instead of simple remote desktop?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, remote-access, remote-desktop

I want to have a computer at home without monitor, keyboard or anything. Just PC running 24/7 so I can connect to it from other computers and run some complex computations there. I would like to do updates and maintance from time to time manually but I need to be sure that PC will not turn off or restart whenever it wants. I think the simpliest method is just to enable remote desktop and disable automatic updates and leave computer turned on.

And then I read about installing hyperV and creating virtual machine and then using remote desktop which is definitely more complicated and time consuming approach (and I will have to learn everything). And here comes the question. Is it worth it in my case? And what are the advantages? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was in your situation I would use the computer with remote desktop and use it similar to a kiosk for computations. Hyper-V would only make sense where you have the proper licensing for it as well as the needs for multiple VM's. If you are still interested I would go a free route and use ESXI. If you want to license the VM's properly (Assuming your running windows VM's) in Hyper-V you will need to purchase a Windows server datacenter license and then you can auto license all of the VM's underneath the Hyper Visor. So unless you have a spare server with the need for multiple nodes then I would just stick with your set-up! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to use just the computer with remote desktop too, but I dont trust Windows OS that it will not turn off or restart in wrong time. It could ruin all computations and deny acces to it. So I will probably learn to use some version of Linux. I heard it is reliable but it will be rough to get used to it.